# using parenthesis in declaration of variable

Tags: java

When & Why parenthesis are used in declaring a variable.For example :

```
 Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
```

Here why Graphics2D are put in Parenthesis and what is the use of these ().

Comment: Your keyword to search is [casting in java](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=casting+in+java&oq=casting+in+java&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.343j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=2&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: This is casting not declaring.

Comment: So what does casting means

Comment: @namanjain casting converts one object type to another (if possible).

Comment: @ryrich Casting isn't conversion, and it's important not to confuse the two.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Casting objects in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306835/casting-objects-in-java)

Comment: @chrylis I'm pretty sure we could argue semantics all day, but what I said is true. Casting is also known as type conversion. Please check out the docs! http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a cast.  You are casting the g object (of type graphics) to a more specific type of Graphics2D

As per the document:

> This Graphics2D class extends the Graphics class to provide more
>   sophisticated control over geometry, coordinate transformations, color
>   management, and text layout. This is the fundamental class for
>   rendering 2-dimensional shapes, text and images on the Java(tm)
>   platform.

Basically you are telling your code to take the g object and treat it like a graphics2d object which has more features.  You can do this because Graphics2D is a "subclass" of graphics.

Comment: So in parenthesis we used the type to which we want to convert the object

Comment: @namanjain It's not converting; it's telling the compiler that you expect that the object is really a subclass of its declared type. If it's not already the type you try to cast it to, you'll get a `ClassCastException`.

Comment: @chrylis - well said!

Answer (score 1):

It's used to cast from one type to another one.

Ex:

```
float floatingNumber = 5.2;
int integerNumber = (int) floatingNumber;
```

In this case, the (int) takes just the integer part from the floating point number stored on "floatingNumber". So integerNumber will now store the value 5, which is the integer part of floatingNumber.