# How can i cast a EditText into an Address?

Tags: java, android, casting, street-address

I'm trying to get a cast of an Address on a EditText.

There is not syntax errors, but the LogCat throws a casting error message, and it doesn't work.

```
geoPoint((Address)direction.getText()); // this is the cast
```

Where `direction` is an `EditText`, and `geoPoint()` is defined like this:

```
public static GeoPoint geoPoint(Address direction){
    geoPoint = new GeoPoint(direction.getLongitude(), direction.getLatitude());
    return geoPoint;
}
```

The idea is to get the coordinates of a postal address

Thanks in advance!

Comment: that's not what cast do. please refer to Java documentation.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP lacks minimal understanding of the notion they are using

Comment: `not sintax erros`, probably not, but there is a big warning telling you it's not going to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [Geocoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) class to get the Address from the String.  Have a look at this answer:

[How can I find the latitude and longitude from address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574644/how-can-i-find-the-latitude-and-longitude-from-address)

Answer (score 0):

Nope! As you can see on the docs, [Address](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html) has nothing to do with [EditText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html). You can only 'cast' on objects from the same class hierarchy. There's another similar question on this subject you may refer to: [Casting objects in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306835/casting-objects-in-java)

What you can do is take the 'String' value of the Address and put it in the EditText using the

```
EditText.setText(address.toString());
```

Good luck!