# Java (String) - what does it do?

Tags: java, string, queue

I was doing some past papers on my exam and I came accross this question :

What does (String) do on line 5 and what is this type of expression called?

Here is line 5 : `String str = (String) D.dequeue ();`

My guess is that it's veryfing if the value we get from `D.dequeue()` is a `String` though I am not sure.

Comment: The keyword is casting. Read the section Casting Objects: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html. Also it seems that you are using a raw collection. Don't if you can use generics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called Casting. The value returned by the `Dequeue` method is cast to a `String` type.

Essentially this operation forces the value to take the type of `String` so that you can assign it to a variable which is also of type `String`. You should note however that casting from one type to another may not always succeed.

For example, this will give you a compile-time error:

```
int a = (int)"123";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = (String) D.dequeue ();
```

It's called **typecasting**. Since you are not using generics you are required to typecast the Object before using it as String.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually making an explicit cast of the object returned by D.dequeue() to String (i.e. transforming it into a String instance).
Take a look at this explanation: [Casting objects in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306835/casting-objects-in-java)