# charvariable=(char)(charvariable+3) what does this syntax mean?

Tags: java

I have been looking around on the internet at caesar ciphers and while I understand the loop I don't understand why this line of code is able to shift a char to another char?  I don't understand this line here:

```
        letter = (char)(letter - 26);
```

When I take (char) out it doesn't work and I have never seen it with the type being in parentheses followed by an operation.

Hopefully this is an easy question and thanks for the help.

```
for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
    {
        // Letter.
        char letter = buffer[i];
        // Add shift to all.
        letter = (char)(letter + shift);
        // Subtract 26 on overflow.
        // Add 26 on underflow.
        if (letter > 'z')
        {
//The following line is the line I don't understand.  Why char in parentheses then another parentheses?
        letter = (char)(letter - 26);
        }
        else if (letter < 'a')
        {
        letter = (char)(letter + 26);
        }
        // Store.
        buffer[i] = letter;
    }
```

Comment: Ugh, my hand slipped. Anyways, please don't use code snippets for code that isn't javascript. Java well not play well with those.

Comment: The char in parenthesis is to do a [cast][1] in java.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306835/casting-objects-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(char)` is a *cast*.  That means that it takes a value which is of one type, and converts it to a value of another type.  Thus, if `x` is an `int`, `(double)x` yields a `double` whose value is the same value as the integer value.

The reason `(char)` is necessary in this expression is that Java does all its integer arithmetic on values of type `int` or `long`.  So even though `letter` is a `char`, in the expression `letter + 26`, `letter` will be automatically converted to an `int`, and then 26 is added to the integer.  `(char)` converts it back to a `char` type (which is an integer value from 0 to 65535).  Java will not automatically convert a larger integer type (`int`, whose values are from -2147483648 to 2147483647) to a shorter integer type (`char`), therefore it's necessary to use a cast.

However, Java does allow this:

```
letter += 26;
```

which has the same effect, and does not require a cast.

Comment: "which has the same effect, and does not require a cast." actually it does an implicit cast mandated by the specification in that case.

Comment: @GáborBakos I think it's clear I was talking about explicit casts.  The implicit cast is in the language rules to define the semantic effect, but there is no reason for the underlying implementation to perform an actual 32-bit addition and a conversion.

Answer (score 0):

There are 26 letters in the english alphabet, and char is an integral type

```
char ch = 'Z' - 25;
System.out.println(ch); // <-- A
```

[JLS-4.2.1 - Integral Types and Values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1) says (in part),

> For `char`, from '\u0000' to '\uffff' inclusive, that is, from 0 to 65535

Comment: I think this does not compile. `'Z' - 25` should be `int`.

Comment: Thanks.  I understand that now.  What I am more confused with is the cast part of it.

Comment: @GáborBakos Tested with Java 8. Works.

Comment: @DarthShiznit It converts the bit pattern from one type to another.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch probably constant folding in that case. `char z = 'Z'; char ch = z-25;` does not.