# What does "Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;" mean and what is the significance of this line in the following code segment?

Tags: java, swing, awt, graphics2d, java-2d

```
public void paint(Graphics g) 
{
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
    g2d.fillOval(0, 0, 30, 30);
    g2d.drawOval(0, 50, 30, 30);        
    g2d.fillRect(50, 0, 30, 30);
    g2d.drawRect(50, 50, 30, 30);

    g2d.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 100, 30, 30));
}
```

Well, I am new to `JPanel` class and I have slight confusion. `g` is an object of `Graphics` class.  So, what does `(Graphics2D) g` mean as in this line `g` seems as if it is a method and not an object? Further, can anyone tell me why `Graphics2D` class cannot be instantiated?

Comment: Note: `public void paint(Graphics g) { ..` Since this is a `JComponent`, the correct method to override is `paintComponent` and we should always call the super method first to ensure that the BG is painted. So it would better be `protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) { super.paintComponent(g); ..` What is written above makes me think this code comes from some other source. Given the snippet overrides the wrong method and fails to paint the BG, I suggest to **find a new source of code examples.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`g` is a variable, not a method. It is declared in the method declaration because it is a parameter of the method (i.e., it needs to be passed whenever the function is called).

The `(Graphics2D)` cast allows you to treat `g` as a `Graphics2D` object. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306835/casting-objects-in-java) for more information on casts.

You cannot initiate `Graphics2D` because it is an [abstract class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html), meaning that it has some methods that are specific to implementation.

Comment: @Subler Huh..  Right you are!  I deleted some noise. :)