# Create object of class of another object

Tags: java, object

Is it possible to use constructor of class of diffrent object? Imagine two classes: A and B extends A. We make object

```
A x = new B(arg);
```

And then (pseudo-code!)

```
A y = new (x.getClass())(arg);
```

Can I reach this effect without iffing and casing through all possible inheritors of A?

Comment: You can create an instance of super class with new subclass(). But in other case no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reflection is probably what you want, still it's not encouraged:

```
A y = x.getClass().getConstructor(ArgType.class).newInstance(args);
```

Will create a new instance of `B`.

<sub><sub>credits for @Hogler, for pointing out a mistake.</sub></sub>

Comment: Does not work: the method newInstance()  (...)   is not applicable for argument (EgClass)

Comment: `x.getClass().getConstructor(TypeOfArg.class).newInstance(arg);`…

Comment: This is exactly what i needed

Answer (score 0):

You can typecast the object if one object inherits the other. Look at this link for more information: [Casting objects in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306835/casting-objects-in-java)