# Java - what does "(Customer) v.get(i)" do?

Tags: java

I'm new to java, I have the code below (v is a vector)
and I don't understand this:

> (Customer) v.get(i)

Please explain to me .tks

```
public void insert(Customer c) {
    boolean checkExist = true;
    if (checkExist && !isIn(c,v)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
            int check = c.compareTo((Customer) v.get(i));
            if (check < 0) {
                Customer x = new Customer();
                x = (Customer) v.get(i);
                v.set(i, c);
                c = x;
            }
        }
        v.add(c);
    }
}
public boolean isIn(Customer c, Vector els) {
    c = new Customer();
    for (int i = 0; i < els.size(); i++) {
        if (c.equals(els.get(i))) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You almost certainly don't want the `c = new Customer();` line. It overwrites the value that you are passing in as a parameter; you may as well not pass in `Customer c` at all.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289393/casting-variables-in-java

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306835/casting-objects-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show us how `v` is declared.

In the following two lines there's a harmless bug:

```
Customer x = new Customer();
x = (Customer) v.get(i);
```

On the first line a new Customer object is created, but it's never being used, and after the assignment on the following line - this object is eligible to garbage-collection.

These two lines can be substituted by:

```
Customer x = (Customer) v.get(i);
```

The reason there is a need to use casting `(Customer)` is in case `v` is declared to hold a more general type object, and we need to cast it to `Customer` in order to assign it to `x` and use `Customer` properties and methods.

For more about casting see [`Casting Objects`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) section.

Answer (score 0):

`v.get(i)` gets the *i*th member of v, and `(Customer)` casts it to a Customer class.

See the [tutorial, "Casting Objects."](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is casting the object returned by `v.get(i)` to a Customer, so the object returned can be treated as a Customer, accessing methods in the Customer class/interface.  If the object returned cannot be cast to a Customer, because it does not extend/implement Customer, it will throw a ClassCastException.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = (Customer) v.get(i);
```

Means that your typecasting the i-element from your vector to the class Customer. In simpler words making v.get(i) of the type Customer.