# How can I call a subclass method using a superclass object?

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass, superclass

I'm having an issue with my code where I need to call a subclass method using a superclass object. Is there any possible way to do this or a work around? I'm completely stumped and there is no helpful answer for my issue.

```
    String basicCommand = commands[0];
    String advCommand = commands[1];
    String perCommand = commands[2];
    if (objectName.get(advCommand)instanceof Circle){
        objectName.get(advCommand);
        //.changeSize(reader.convertToInt(perCommand));
```

`advcommand` is of type `Shape` which is a superclass of the class `Circle`, and the method `changesize()` is within `Circle`.

*Data is within a hashmap.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Casting objects in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306835/casting-objects-in-java)

Comment: Yes, [downcasting](http://stackoverflow.com/a/380828/1810429).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to instantiate it based on the classname:

```
  Class cc = Class.forName(advCommand); 
  Circle c = (Circle)c.newInstance();
  c.changeSize(reader.convertToInt(perCommand));
```

Comment: You Genius Man! Thank you so much this works however the code is a little different as you have to get the object from the hashmap, I had no idea you had to cast it, if possible could you explain casting something in more detail and what it does exactly?                                              

   ` ((Circle) objectName.get(advCommand)).changeSize(reader.convertToInt(perCommand));`

Comment: yes, try this: https://howtoprogramwithjava.com/java-cast/ . would appreciate an upvote + correct answer check!