# Instantiate through inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, instantiation

[I know its via inheritance when we say B c = new C(); but what is the difference with C c = new C()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vg315.png)

I know this code works but the why and how is my epidemic. when I did my own math (using pen and paper) it gave me 80. But when I read through the OCA paper I noticed they arrived at the same answer but for different reasons.

***"When the program is run, the main() method will call the max() method in C with parameters 10 and 20 because the actual object referenced by 'c' is of class C. This method will call the max() method in B with the parameters 20 and 40. The max() method in B will in turn call the max() method in A with the parameters 20 and 40. The max() method in A will return 40 to the max() method in B. The max() method in B will return 80 to the max() method in C. And finally the max() of C will return 80 in main() which will be printed out."***

Which sounds more or less Greek to me, please help. Wanna know what it means to write B c = new C(); and how it differs to C c = new C();

Comment: what is your own math?

Comment: `B c = new C();` vs `C c = new C();` has no effect on the output of `max`.

Comment: can you please provide proper explanation of your question with code also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we have `C c = new C(); B b = c;`

A `C` object is constructed but you only see its `B` part through `b`. Just like when different people see you differently: for example your friend see you as a friend but your parent see you as a child even if it is the same seen person (you are unique but people see you differently). Then talking to this object through `b` only permits to talk with a `B` vision of it (only what is defined as public in `B`). Of course the object is a `C` one then if you use a `B` method on it is answers with its `C` behavior to it. This is called **polymorphism** (different *looks* for a single object) by **subtyping** (looks are related to each other by inclusion).

A real life example of such usage could be the following. I imagine that you agree that a `Car` is a `Vehicule` as a `Van` is a `Vehicle`. Then when you build a parking you didn't design it only for cars but for any `Vehicle`, as you can park a `Car` or a `Van`. So it is very useful to *see* a `Car` or a `Van` as a simple `Vehicle`.

In java this could give:

```
class VehicleThatCouldBeParked {}
class Car extends VehicleThatCouldBeParked {}
class Van extends VehicleThatCouldBeParked {}

...
VehicleThatCouldBeParked []parking = ne VehicleThatCouldBeParked[100]; // build a parking with hundred locations
...
Car myCar = new Car(); // some car
...
Van myVan = new Van(); // some van
...
parking[76] = myCar; // my car is parked in slot 77
parking[34] = myVan; // my van is parked in slot 35
...
```

This is very important in many situations (even in real life) no to be aware of some details of objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you write `B c = new C();` the result will be the same because of dynamic binding. At runtime the object type will be used to resolve the method to call. The object type of c (`C`) ist still the same, so no difference.

The only difference in the code is, that the type of the reference has changed.

Answer (score 0):

At runtime, the method of actual object will be called. 
The difference however depends on your usage where possibly you have B defining a behavior and C, AND for the sake of answer D, E and F may be implementing it in a specific way. Now using the reference of B type, you can create a common contract for client. 
 Will suggest reading basic OOPs concept from tons of resources on internet.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are concerning is about polymorphism. If you have variable (imagine it as  box) pointing to class (let's call it `A`), pointing to some class, you can put in this box any class that extends `A`.

On you further problem, I advice reading carefully the post:
[Casting objects in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306835/casting-objects-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

```
abstract class A {
    protected abstract void print();
}

class B extends A {

    @Override
    protected void print() {
        System.out.println("I am in B");
    }

    public void print1() {
        System.out.println("No in A");
    }
}

class C extends A {

    @Override
    protected void print() {
        System.out.println("I am in C");
    }

    public void print1() {
        System.out.println("No in A");
    }
}
```

> A a = new C();  a.print();
>
> //a.**print1**(); can't resolve method print1()
>
> //**B** b = new C(); incompatible type