# Casting Objects -- How do they work?

Tags: java, casting

I have a Person class, and Object class is just the Object class of Java. I have a Student class that extends the Person Class as well. Can somebody explain why in these different scenarios I get errors when casting and some work?

```
Person p = (Person) new Object(); // error
Person p = (Person) new Student(“Steve”, 21, 12345); // works
Object o = new Person(“Steve”, 21); // works
Person p = (Person) o; // works
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306835/casting-objects-in-java mean while you can read this

Comment: Because a Person is a Person, but an Object isn't.

Answer (score 2):

Casting doesn't magically turn an object into something else.
It just tells the compiler to attempt to access a piece of data as a different type.

In the first example, you create an Object, which can't be cast into Person. Casting does not magically transform things.

In the second example, you create a Student object. Since Student inherits from Person, you can also consider it of type person.

Line 3: Again, you create a Person object but you hold it in a variable of type object. That doesn't change what the object actually is, which is why the downcasting to Person works.

Answer (score 0):

Object  class is Base Class of all java classes ,That's why reference of Object capable to hold object of any java class .

But if any class extends another class then child class not directly extends Object class in this case multilevel Inheritance concept implements implicitly .

In Your case

`Person` class is **super class** ,

`Student` class is **sub class**.

That's  means Student class acquire properties of Person class , Casting is possible in this case as wall as Student extends Object class through Person Class.

Answer (score 0):

It's OK to cast a child(sub) class object to a parent(super) class because child class already know and has everything(ie. variables and methods) from the inheritance of parent class, but not the other way around.

Example:

```
Parent class has method a1().
Child class added a method a2().
Child automatically gets a1() through inheritance.
Parent knows nothing about a2().
```