# Sorting through ArrayList of Objects, Add given Instance to ArrayList of given instances issue

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm getting the error

> no suitable method found for add(Object), method Collected.add(Student is not applicable)

when I try the following code. I swear I've done it this way before? So confused. Appreciate any insights. Cheers

```
    //Sort and display list of Student objects by sortBy (surname or id)
public static void sortAndDisplayStudents(String sortBy, ArrayList<Object> objList) {
    ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();

    //Add all Objcets in objList that are a Student
    for(Object s: objList) {
        if(s instanceof Student) {
            students.add(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cast `s` to `Student` before adding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to avoid any errors, change the way you construct the array list:

```
ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<>(); 
ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
```

As for the add method, you want to cast to the passing object otherwise the JVM will not know that the object being passed is `instanceof` Student:

```
students.add((Student) s);
```

Also, you should get an [IDE](https://www.eclipse.org/home/index.php), they usually solve these problems before they happen.

Comment: Thanks! I am using Netbeans though I didn't get any warnings.

Comment: @Snar3 netbeans is a confusing IDE in my opinion, try using Eclipse. =)

Answer (score 2):

`ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();` shows that `students` is a `ArrayList` that contain the Object `Student`.

Therefore you need to cast your `s` Object to `Student` before adding it to the `students` list. like such `students.add((Student)s);` Here is how you cast [Object in Java.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306835/casting-objects-in-java#5306895)