# Cast instance of Object with Comparable

Tags: java, oop, object, comparable

I was looking at a mergeSort method, and i have some questions.
There is a cast of Object into Comparable, that is an interface.

```
((Comparable)dest[j-1]).compareTo((Comparable)dest[j])
```

What the compiler exactly does when there is cast interface?
The `.compareTo` method is not defined in `Object` class.
An interface has only abstract method. How is possible to use in Object?

```
private static void mergeSort(Object src[], Object dest[], int low, int high) {
    int length = high - low;

    // Insertion sort on smallest arrays
    if (length < 7) {
        for (int i=low; i<high; i++)
          for (int j=i; j>low && ((Comparable)dest[j-1]).compareTo((Comparable)dest[j]) >0; j--)
              swap(dest, j, j-1);
        return;
    }
    // Recursively sort halves of dest into src
    int mid = (low + high)/2;
    mergeSort(dest, src, low, mid);
    mergeSort(dest, src, mid, high);

    // If list is already sorted, just copy from src to dest.  This is an
    // optimization that results in faster sorts for nearly ordered lists.
    if (((Comparable)src[mid-1]).compareTo((Comparable)src[mid]) <= 0) {
        System.arraycopy(src, low, dest, low, length);
        return;
    }
    // Merge sorted halves (now in src) into dest
    for(int i = low, p = low, q = mid; i < high; i++){
        if (q>=high || p<mid && ((Comparable)src[p]).compareTo(src[q])<=0)
            dest[i] = src[p++];
        else
            dest[i] = src[q++];
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Casting objects in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306835/casting-objects-in-java)

Comment: Your question can be translated like "Is some Object *less than*, *equal to* or *greater than* other Object". Do you really think that this is the goal you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dest[j-1]` is a reference, it refers an `Object`, this `Object` might has implemented `Comparable`.

With `(Comparable)dest[j-1]`, you are telling the compiler *Trust me, I 'm Comparable*.

At runtime, if this object is comparable, that's fine. It not, `ClassCastException` will be thrown.

```
Object o = 1; // Integer is Comparable
System.out.println(((Comparable)(o)).compareTo(0)); // 1

Object o = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // ArrayList is not Comparable
System.out.println(((Comparable)(o)).compareTo(0)); // ClassCastException
```

Comment: Did you intend to say "ArrayList is *not* Comparable" in the comment?

Answer (score 0):

This is partly due to a hangover from the old days before generics when many of the core Java functions took `Object` as parameters and you had to cast stuff all over the place.

Also, the `Arrays` class can also sort intrinsic things like `int` etc.

What is happening here is that the `mergeSort` is assuming the object implements [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) and calls it's `compareTo` method. This assumption will cause a *fail fast* [ClassCastException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html) so it's not a bad assumption.

TLDR: In most cases the object **will** implement `Comparable` so it is safe.